# JavaScript Vue insert mutiple first name as mutiple rows in database. Should I use for each loop for that?

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, vue.js

My View

```
<div>
 <div class="work-experiences">
   <div class="form-row" v-for="(minordatabase, index) in minorsDetail" :key="index">
     <div class="col" style="margin-left: 8%;">
       <label id="minorHeading">Minor's full name</label>
       <input v-model="minorsDetail.first_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Minor Full Name"/>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button @click="addExperience" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Add Minor</button>
    <button @click="removeExperience" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info">Remove Minor</button>
   </div>
</div>
<div>
 <b-button variant="primary" v-on:click="submitForm();">SUBMIT</b-button>
</div>
```

My Script

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

export default {
    name: 'App',

    data() {
    return {
     minorsDetail: [
        {
          first_name: [],
        }
      ],
    },

    methods:{
      /** below is an experience that adds news input field **/
      addExperience(){
          this.minorsDetail.push({
            first_name: ''
          })
        },

       /** this removes the experience **/
       removeExperience: function(todo){
         var index = this.minorsDetail.indexOf(todo)
         this.minorsDetail.splice(index, 1)
        },

       /** submit function that sends data to MySQL database using axios post **/

       submitForm(){
         let payload = {
         first_name: this.minorsDetail.first_name
         };

         axios({
          url: 'http://localhost:7070/player_minors',
          method: 'post',
          data: payload
         })
         .then(function (response) {
         console.log(response);
         })
         .catch(function (error) {
         console.log(error);
         });
       }
    }
 }
```

Currently when I add multiple first_name and click submitForm() button, it submits only one first_name. Example:

**first_name** = ['David','John','Jack']

MySQL Database receives only one name **David**.

Is there a way when I submitForm() it submits as multiple first_name into MySQL database as

- row 1 : David
- row 2 : John
- row 3 : Jack

Comment: How are you using AngularJS, React, and Vue in the same application?

Comment: I am using vue.js only. I just modified my question and forgot to remove my tags. Just updated my question again. Thank You for reminding me about that.